# What is the best way to parse sms

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am developing an app for parsing sms into strings which i want to store in sqlite db.

Here is the sample of how the sms look.
Sample for airtime payment.

```
Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to KKL(0909xxxx).
Your Balance is UGX10,000.
Thank you for using KKL MobileMoney.
```

Sample for mobile money deposit

```
You have received UGX100,000 from 09006700. Reason:J.
Your balance is UGX170,000.
```

Sample for mobile money sending

```
You have sent UGX10,000 to 08970000.
Reason:j.
Your balance is UGX120,000.
Thank you for using KKL MobileMoney.
```

What i am interested in is:
 -the amount send/received /paid.
-the number received from/sent to/payment made to.
- the reason 
-the balance .

So far i have tried using split function .

It is not consistent though.I am using the array index of the string token but on some strings i get an index out bound exception yet on some strings it works.

Here is the code i have so far...but works not consistently!

```
if (str.startsWith(RECEIVED))
            {
                // for mm deposit
                Log.e("msg", str);
                String delimeter="[ .]+";
                String[] tokens= str.split(delimeter);
                for (int i=0;i < tokens.length;i++)
                {
                    Log.e("Test",tokens[i]);    
                    }                       
                    String amount =tokens[3];
                    String reason =tokens[6].trim();            
                    String number=tokens[5];
                    String balance=tokens[11];              
                    Log.e("Amount",amount);
                    Log.e("reasons",reason);
                    Log.e("number",number);
                    Log.e("balance",balance);
                    String type="Deposit";
                    db.addrecord(amount, type, reason, number, balance);
                    db.close();
            }
            else if(str.startsWith(SEND))
            {   
                // for sent sms
                Log.e("msg", str);           
            String delimeter="[ .]+";
            String[] tokens= str.split(delimeter);
            for (int i=0;i < tokens.length;i++)
            {
                Log.e("Test",tokens[i]);    
                }                   
                String amount =tokens[3];
                String reason =tokens[6].trim();                
                String number=tokens[5];
                String balance=tokens[11];                          
                Log.e("Amount",amount);
                Log.e("reasons",reason);
                Log.e("number",number);
                Log.e("balance",balance);               
                String type="Payment";
                db.addrecord(amount, type, reason, number, balance);
                db.close();
            }

        else if(str.startsWith(AIRTIMEPAYMENT))
        {       // for airtime sms
            Log.e("msg", str);
            String delimeter="[ .]+";
            String[] tokens= str.split(delimeter);
            for (int i=0;i < tokens.length;i++)
            {
                Log.e("Test",tokens[i]);    
                }                       
                String amount =tokens[4];
                String reason =tokens[0]+ " "+ tokens[1];   
                String number=tokens[7];
                String balance=tokens[11];              
                Log.e("Amount",amount);
                Log.e("reasons",reason);
                Log.e("number",number);
                Log.e("balance",balance);
                String type="Air Time ";
                db.addrecord(amount, type, reason, number, balance);
                db.close();
        }
```

Any tips/advice on how best to handle the parsing?

I am beginner java/android programmer!

Ronald

Here is the edit i have made to

```
private Map<String, String> parseSms(String s){
    Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();
    s = s.replace("\n", "");
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s, ".");
    while (t.hasMoreTokens()){
        String b = t.nextToken().trim();
        if (b.startsWith("You have sent") ||(b.startsWith("You have received"))){
            String type = getType(b);
            String parsed = parseAmount(b);
            String number = parseNumber(b);
            ret.put("amount", parsed);
            ret.put("number", number);
            ret.put("type", type);
        }else if(b.startsWith("Your")){//balance
            String parsed = parseAmount(b);
            ret.put("balance", parsed);
        }else if (b.startsWith("Reason")){

            ret.put("reason", b.toString());
        }
        else if( b.startsWith("Airtime"))
        {
              String type = getType(b);
              String parsed = parseAmount(b);
              String number = parseNumber(b);
              ret.put("amount", parsed);
              ret.put("number", number);
              ret.put("reason", "Air Time Payment");
              ret.put("type", type);
          }else if(b.startsWith("Your")){//balance
            String parsed = parseAmount(b);
            ret.put("balance", parsed);

        }


    }

    return ret;
}
```

It solved the problem.

Comment: Why can't you extract the balance only, which should be simple, and deduce the deltas from history?

Comment: Hi. which history? i only have access to sms received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to parsing more robustly.

Replace pertinent strings with your constants. Using Map is a lot safer than String[] when it comes to looping. You can also use match with regexp.

```
private void test(){

    String sms = "You have sent UGX10,000 to 08970000.\n" +
            "Reason:j.\n" +
            "Your balance is UGX120,000.\n" +
            "Thank you for using KKL MobileMoney.";

    /*String rec = "You have received UGX100,000 from 09006700. Reason:J.\n" +
            "Your balance is UGX170,000.";
    String air = "Airtime payment made for UGX5,000 to KKL(0909xxxx).\n" +
            "Your Balance is UGX10,000.\n" +
            "Thank you for using KKL MobileMoney.";
    */
    Map<String, String> data = parseSms(sms);
    saveToDB(data);

}


private void saveToDB(Map<String, String> data){
    db.addrecord(data.get("amount"), data.get("type"), data.get("reason"), data.get("number"), data.get("balance"));
    db.close();
}

private Map<String, String> parseSms(String s){
    Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();
    s = s.replace("\n", "");
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s, ".");
    while (t.hasMoreTokens()){
        String b = t.nextToken().trim();
        if (b.startsWith("You have sent") ||  (b.startsWith("Airtime") || (b.startsWith("You have received")))){
            String type = getType(b);
            String parsed = parseAmount(b);
            String number = parseNumber(b);
            ret.put("amount", parsed);
            ret.put("number", number);
            ret.put("type", type);
        }else if(b.startsWith("Your")){//balance
            String parsed = parseAmount(b);
            ret.put("balance", parsed);
        }else if (b.startsWith("Reason")){
            ret.put("reason", b.toString());
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private String getType(String s){
    if (s.startsWith("You have sent"))//Use your constants
        return "Payment";
    else if (s.startsWith("Airtime"))
        return "Air time";
    else if (s.startsWith("You have received"))
        return "Deposit";

    return "Unknown";
}


private String parseNumber(String s){
    String numberFragment = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' '), s.length());//extract number
    return numberFragment;
}

private String parseAmount(String s){
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean parsingNumber = false;
    for (char c: arr){
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            parsingNumber = true;
        if (Character.isLetter(c)  && c != ',' )
            parsingNumber = false;
        if (parsingNumber && c == ' ')//we have reached end of digit series
            break; //done
        if (parsingNumber)
            sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the code. Let me test and give feedback!

Comment: Hello. The airtime part failed on the reason token. Reason i guess is that the string does not contain the word "reason"

Comment: True, in your supplied text, the Reason part was missing for the SENT sms text. I don't know where and how it failed but you are now using Map and it's very easy to check if a key exists in the map before acting on it. For example in the code where you save to the database, just check  `if (data.containsKey(key))` . If not, the hardcode Reason value to empty string or any value you like.

Answer (score 3):

The best way of parsing texts of this kind is to use Regular Expression (RegEx).

So.. you define several regex in your app... and check if string is matching ... and if yes... then you found it!.

Spend some time learning regular expression.. they are used very much in parsing. You can use site http://rubular.com/ for validating/testing your regular expression.

one example of code for parsing/matching a string with regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s(.*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(strAlarm);
if (m.matches(){
    int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    long timeInMsec = Long.parseLong(m.group(2));
    String message = m.group(3);
    ....
}
```

The example above parses strings of this kind "323 432 123 zxchzxc anything kjhzcx"

As a small help.. let's parse your 2nd example.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^You\\s+have\\s+received\\s+(\\S+)\\sfrom\\s+(\\d+)\\.\\sReason:\\w\\.\\s*Your\\sbalance\\sis\\s(\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(smsTextHere);
if (m.matches(){
    //m.group(1) -- is string containing UGX100,000
    //m.group(1) -- is string containing 09006700
    //m.group(1) -- is string containing UGX170,000.
}
```

Comment: yes... just 2-3 lines of java code to parse any string ;)